# How to read a text file with other encoding than UFT8 or UTF16 in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

If I read a textfile using FileIO.ReadTextAsync, ReadLinesAsync or a DataReader, I can only specify a member of the UnicodeEncoding enum for the encoding. This includes for some reason only Utf8, Utf16BE and Utf16LE. How can I read a text file with another encoding (like Windows-1252 or even regular Unicode (with 2 Bytes for all characters)) then?

This may be important if Windows Store Apps share text files with Desktop applications or read text files from the internet.

Comment: This is not for "some reason", this is a hard stop to the never ending lossage of reading text files with the wrong encoding.  Utf-16 is 'regular Unicode' and uses 2 bytes.  You can spin this yourself by reading binary data and converting text with the Encoding class.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I did not know that Encoding.Unicode is actually UTF-16 LE (that actually uses 2 or 4 bytes). I assumed the same reason for the "hard stop" but I wanted to know for sure. It does make sense. Reading UTF-8 or UTF-16 files with BOM always succeeds, even if I pass the wrong encoding (which is obviously ignored when a BOM is present). Well, we still could face problems when reading an UTF coded text file without BOM (I checked that). But such a file would be very rare. Thanks for the hint to Encoding.GetString. I forgot about that :-) Would have marked that as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hans' comment actually gave the answer to my question. Sample for Windows-1252:

```
string filePath = ...
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
byte[] fileData = buffer.ToArray();
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
string text = encoding.GetString(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

@JürgenBayer `buffer.ToArray()` wasn't available for me.

So, instead of writing:

```
string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

I wrote:

```
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
byte[] fileData;
CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, out fileData);
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
string text = encoding.GetString(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
```

Comment: ToArray is an extension method from the class WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions available if the namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime is included. But your code looks good as well :-)